# magento 2 website move to another store

Tags: magento2

I have multi store setup and multi web sites for each store.

```
like
  store 1
     store view a
     store view b
 store 2
     store view c
```

I want to move  store view b to store 2
is it possible how can achieve it.

Comment: Store not have website but, website have store and store have store view.

Comment: yes I want to move store view one from to another

Comment: Go to  menu Stores > All Stores (First menu) > And Under store view column heading you have "website b" that one edit view there you can change store of store view.